# How to get supported size with 18.5:9 or 18:9 ratio for camera?

Tags: android, camera, size

I am using a custom camera and used the full-screen resolution to display the preview in the entire screen of the device. We have a native method to get all supported size for the picture, preview and video either using **`Camera`** or **`Camera Manager`** for all types of device. Check below code which I used to retrieve all supported size for the camera.

- **Using Camera**

  ```
  Camera.Parameters parameters = mCameraHelper.getCamera().getParameters();

  // Images supported size by device
  List<Camera.Size> pictureSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

  // Camera Preview supported size by device
  List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

  // Video supported size by device
  List<Camera.Size> videoSizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
  ```
- **Using Camera Manager**

  ```
  CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

  try {
      for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
          CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);


          StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

          // Images supported size by device
          Size[] pictureSizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

          // Video supported size by device
          Size[] videoSizes = map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class);
      }
  } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.e(TAG, "setUpCameraOutputs: catch: " + e.getMessage());
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "setUpCameraOutputs: catch: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  ```

I have used this code and tested in **Samsung A8+** device and Below are the sizes which I get in output after running above code.

```
==============================================
================  Preview size    ============
Preview size : 0 : Width: 1080 , Height: 1920
Preview size : 1 : Width: 1080 , Height: 1440
Preview size : 2 : Width: 1088 , Height: 1088

==============================================
================  Picture size    ============
Picture size : 0 : Width: 3456 , Height: 4608
Picture size : 1 : Width: 2592 , Height: 4608
Picture size : 2 : Width: 3456 , Height: 3456
Picture size : 3 : Width: 2448 , Height: 3264
Picture size : 4 : Width: 1836 , Height: 3264
Picture size : 5 : Width: 2448 , Height: 2448
Picture size : 6 : Width: 1152 , Height: 2048
Picture size : 7 : Width: 1080 , Height: 1920

==============================================
================   Video size   ==============

Video size : 0 : Width: 1080 , Height: 1920
Video size : 1 : Width: 1080 , Height: 1440
Video size : 2 : Width: 1072 , Height: 1072
```

Comparing to above output size to real native **Samsung A8+** device camera sizes which are listed below. From that, I want an 18.5:9 ratio size which is TAG as "I need this size" in below list.

```
==============================================
================  Picture size    ============
Picture size : 0 : Width: 3456 , Height: 4608
Picture size : 1 : Width: 2592 , Height: 4608
Picture size : 2 : Width: 2240 , Height: 4608    <--- I need this size
Picture size : 3 : Width: 3456 , Height: 3456
Picture size : 4 : Width: 1836 , Height: 3264
Picture size : 5 : Width: 2448 , Height: 2448

==============================================
================   Video size   ==============

Video size : 0 : Width: 1080 , Height: 1920
Video size : 1 : Width: 1080 , Height: 2224    <--- I need this size
Video size : 2 : Width: 1072 , Height: 1072
Video size : 2 : Width: 720 , Height: 1280
Video size : 2 : Width: 480 , Height: 640
```

**My Query:** When I used a higher resolution for full-screen preview from output size using above code, Camera preview stretch because it doesn't have resolutions of 18.5:9 ratio.

So, How can I get this type of resolution like 18:9 or 18.5:9 ratio, which is available in nowadays in new devices we called full-vision device or notch display. I need proper solutions which can works in all devices and give me the same size which is listed in the device native camera for full-screen for camera preview.

Comment: Have you tried the Samsung camera SDK? It's similar to camera2, but may return more variants.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn, I will try your solutions.

Comment: Please update about your findings. This kind of first-hand evidence is very important for others, too.

Comment: Sure, I will update if I found the proper solution.

Comment: Hello @AlexCohn, I have tried your solutions but Samsung SDK also returns the same resolution which native method return.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. So, this may be yet another private feature of a Samsung camera. I wouldn't be surprised if they silently let you set the desired, not-listed size after all. But even if they don't, you can easily crop the image to desired resolution (except if you planned to use MediaRecorder for video).

Comment: One more note: in your tables above, width and height are swapped. Even in portrait mode, preview frames are always delivered as-is. Rotation may be applied to Jpeg and video, but for preview, it is controlled on the display side, rotating the surface or texture view.