# Camera2 Samsung Galaxy s9 Preview Size

Tags: android, camera, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

I have been using Camera2 and based a lot of it of the Google Camera2 examples. I'm running into some problems when dealing with aspect ratios on different phones.

I get the largest output size and set the preview; this seems to always be a 4:3 aspect ratio. On a Pixel, Galaxy S9, Galaxy Note 8, and Moto G5+ the aspect ratio is always 4:3.

On a Pixel, Galaxy Note 8, and Moto G5+ the stream going to the preview is a 4:3 aspect ratio. The stream on that is being drawn on the Samsung Galaxy S9 is 16:9 aspect ratio. Why is the S9 choosing to stream a different size than I set it to? I set the preview to the right size, but what is being outputted is not what I set.

The general outline of what I'm doing is as follows:

```
List<Size> outputSizes = Arrays.asList(streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(renderingClass));

Final Size previewOutputSize = Collections.max(outputSizes, new AreaComparator());

((AspectRatioTextureView) preview).setAspectRatio(previewOutputSize.getWidth(), previewOutputSize.getHeight());

preview.getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(previewOutputSize.getWidth(), previewOutputSize.getHeight());


previewRequestBuilder = camera.getCaptureRequestBuilder(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

camera.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), new CaptureListener());
```

Comment: 1) what size do you request on S9? 2) what size do you get? 3) do you set jpeg size as well?

Comment: 1) 3024x4032
2) How do I check this? Is this available some where in the CaptureResult in the callback? All I know is it's giving me something with a 16:9 aspect ratio.
3) No

Comment: I don't believe S9 supports 3024x4032 preview size. I think it has 2160p maximum. Note that even in portrait orientation, you must request the size in 'landscape; orientation (see *[Why camera2 supported preview size width always bigger than height?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685806/192373)*). 4032x3024 seems to be their maximum *picture* resolution.

Comment: OnImageAvailable() callback gives you (with ImageReader.acquireLatestImage()), an [android.media.Image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image) which has methods [getWidth()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#getWidth()) and getHeigh().

Comment: The ImageReader is giving me 3024x4032, but that's for a still capture and I'm explicitly setting that width/height.

Comment: Is there a way to get the supported preview sizes for Camera2? The 3024x4032 size is being retrieved from streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(TextureView.class)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296391/how-to-get-supported-size-with-18-59-or-189-ratio-for-camera) you can find a code snippet for getting the list of supported sizes. As you will see, this info should be taken with a grain of salt.